# How to interact with dropdown having html tag as input instead of select in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I've dropdown control in the web application having following html code

```
<input class="dynamic-list-widget-input ui-widget ui-widget-content" title="" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false">
```

I've tried accessing using selenium webdriver  through xpath(relative/absolute), cssSelector but no to avail i got following exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='With-Attachment']/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/span/input"}
Command duration or timeout: 10.12 seconds
```

Comment: Your XPath is obviously incorrect. If you want help, post more HTML. Also have a read through [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It looks very likely you get the wrong xpath for that input element.

if you are using Chrome, you can do as follows:

1. right click on the element in the webpage.
2. click "inspect element" in pop up menu
3. right click the highlighted html code on the right, the then click "copy xpath"

you will get the xpath of that element and compare what it is in your code.